# Why the server side didn’t return a correct function call statement when running the JSONP cross origin demo?

Tags: javascript, node.js, cross-domain

So I just run a [demo](https://github.com/FatDong1/cross-domain) to learn about JSONP cross origin.The demo is running with node.js.
Here is the index.html:

```html
<p>hello world</p>
<script>
    function myFunction (data) {
        alert('get the data successfully，data changes after 2 seconds！');
        let p = document.getElementsByTagName('p')[0];
        setTimeout(function () {
            p.innerHTML = data.message
        }, 2000);
    }
</script>
<script src="http://localhost:3001?callback=myFunction"></script>
</body>
```

Here is the serverRes.js:

```js
var express = require('express');
var app = express();

var responsePort = 3001;

app.get('/', function (req, res) {
    var callbackName = req.query.callback;   // myFunction
    console.log(callbackName);
    res.send(callbackName+"({'message': 'hello world from JSONP!'});");
    // myFunction({'message': 'hello world from JSONP!'})
})

app.listen(responsePort, function () {
    console.log("jsonp_responser server listening on port " + responsePort);
});
```

Anyway,it actually works.When I go to the port 3000,the 'Hello world' changes to 'hello world from JSONP!' after 2 seconds,which means the broswer actually get the data from server side .Here I can see the response:
[image]

Seems no problems.But when I go to the port 3001,what I see is:
[image]

This really confused me since there is an error in the console(And I can't get what it says about),and the text displayed is `undefined({'message': 'hello world from JSONP!'})`, instead of `myFunction({'message': 'hello world from JSONP!'})`.This is really strange.
I have also tried to print `req.query.callback`,`req`,`req.query`.They are all printed normally in the terminal.So why there is an error in console and why the text is 'undefined' instead of the function name 'myFunction'?

Comment: You went to `http://localhost:3001` there are no GET request parameters on that url so the `req.query.callback` value wouldnt be created, eg you would need to use `http://localhost:3001/?callback=myFunction`

Comment: As for the parentNode errors none of your code uses parentNode, at least the code you posted doesnt. Check to see if that error isnt coming from an injected script like from a chrome extension

Comment: @PatrickEvans Yes,you are right.I have closed all chrome extensions and the error disappeared.And when I go to the url `http://localhost:3001/?callback=myFunction`,I can see the `myFunction({'message': 'hello world from JSONP!'})`.